# Is it possible to increase the 256 character limit in excel validation drop down boxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating the validation dynamically and have hit a 256 character limit. My validation looks something like this:

```
Level 1, Level 2, Level 3, Level 4.....
```

Is there any way to get around the character limit other then pointing at a range?

The validation is already being produced in VBA. Increasing the limit is the easiest way to avoid any impact on how the sheet currently works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no way around the 256 character limit, Joel Spolsky explains why here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/fog0000000319.html.

You could however use VBA to get close to replicating the functionality of the built in validation by coding the Worksheet_Change event. Here's a mock up to give you the idea. You will probably want to refactor it to cache the ValidValues, handle changes to ranges of cells, etc...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ValidationRange As Excel.Range
Dim ValidValues(1 To 100) As String
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Valid As Boolean
Dim Msg As String
Dim WhatToDo As VbMsgBoxResult

    'Initialise ValidationRange
    Set ValidationRange = Sheet1.Range("A:A")

    ' Check if change is in a cell we need to validate
    If Not Intersect(Target, ValidationRange) Is Nothing Then

        ' Populate ValidValues array
        For Index = 1 To 100
            ValidValues(Index) = "Level " & Index
        Next

        ' do the validation, permit blank values
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Valid = True
        Else
            Valid = False
            For Index = 1 To 100
                If Target.Value = ValidValues(Index) Then
                    ' found match to valid value
                    Valid = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If Not Valid Then

            Target.Select

            ' tell user value isn't valid
            Msg = _
                "The value you entered is not valid" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "A user has restricted values that can be entered into this cell."

            WhatToDo = MsgBox(Msg, vbRetryCancel + vbCritical, "Microsoft Excel")

            Target.Value = ""

            If WhatToDo = vbRetry Then
                Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            End If

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```